# Matching data using Regular Expressions in perl

Tags: regex, perl, file

In a perl file some text is there and I want to do pattern match. But it is not working?

Example:

```
    open( FH, "perll.txt" );
    while (<FH>) {  $Return .= $_; }
    close(FH);
    if($Return =~ /Session Id.*\:\s.*\-\w+/)
    {
       print "data si$1";
        push(@se,$1);
        next;
        print "yyyyyy@se";
    }
```

perll.txt

```
    Session Id             : fffffa800d461010-1
          this is a good language
    Session Id             : fffffa800d461010-0990wew
```

Output I need is:

```
    fffffa800d461010-1,fffffa800d461010-0990wew   in an array
```

Comment: `use warnings; use diagnostics;` will give you self explanatory warning, and your code has errors.

Answer (score 1):

OK, first off - rule 1 of perl troubleshooting. Turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Second: `while (<FH>) {  $Return .= $_; }` - you're reading the whole file into `$Return`. OK, if that's what you actually mean. But I don't think you need to. It's probably also better written as `local $/; $return = <FH>`.

Thirdly: Please use a 3 argument open with lexical filehandles. 2 Arg has been deprecated quite some time, and that style of `FH` is a global variable, which is just bad form.

Fourth: Your regular expression doesn't capture anything in it's match - so `$1` will always be empty.

Fifth: Your regular expression doesn't have a `g` flag, so it only matches once against your whole file block of text.

This should do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open( my $input, "<", "perll.txt" ) or die $!;

my @session_ids;
while ( <$input> ) {
    my ( $session_id )= m/Session Id\s+:\s*(\S+)/;
    push ( @session_ids, $session_id ) if $session_id; 
}
close ( $input );
print join ( ",", @session_ids );
```

- We open your file as `$input`.
- iterate it, matching `Session Id` and capturing the id with `(\S+)` (one or more non-spaces) into `$session_id`. (Note - needs to be a list context for this to work.
- If `$session_id` is present, we insert it into `@session_ids`.

Note that it does this without needing to read your whole file into memory, which is generally a good thing to avoid unless necessary. (And it doesn't seem to be in your scenario).

Comment: It is not printing the output

Comment: When I run it - using the data you quoted above - I get: `fffffa800d461010-1,fffffa800d461010-0990wew` which was what you wanted? Try adding an `or die` to the open (code edited)

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt work because,

1) **you're trying to copy the entire text in the file to the scalar**  `$Return` and then trying to parse the scalar variable ( which is not the right thing to do ).

Better approach is to **parse the file line-by-line and when there is a match** it should be pushed to the array.

2) And, **in the pattern matching there is no pattern to catch** (you havent specified which pattern needs to be matched or in other words, what is $1? ). That needs to be corrected.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $Return;
my @se;
open( FH, "hello.txt" );
while (<FH>) {
  $Return = $_;

    if($Return =~ /Session Id\s+:\s+(.*)/)
    {

       push(@se,$1);
    }
}
my $output = join(",",@se);
print $output;
close(FH);
```

Comment: Why are you scoping `$Return` outside the loop? It seems redundant in your example? Of course, actually explicitly setting it to `$_` anyway seems somewhat redundant too, when you could: `while ( my $Return = <FH> ) {` which will do the same thing.

Comment: Also - my _opinion_ is that answers are greatly improved by `use strict;` and `use warnings;`  because they serve as better future examples.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
undef $/;
open (FH,"1.txt");
my $string = <FH>;
close(FH);

@arr = $string =~ /Session Id\s+?:\s+?(.*?)\n/isg;

print "@arr\n";
```

Comment: I think this answer would be improved by: More explanation of what's going on, rather than just "try this". e.g. you've slurped the file a different way, and amended how the regex works.  Also - `strict` and `warnings` - the OP doesn't use them, but they're bad practice to omit.

Comment: This is just piece of code. No point of mentioning "use strict; and use warnings;." all time in answer code. Of course the perl developer should know what strict and warnings means in perl.